# Pass custom data to Form Theme in Symfony/Twig

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm new to Symfony, currently working with 4.4, and am trying to implement a simple form theme for one specific form, i.e. the theme is in the same file as the form's `html.twig` file. I have my own `form_row` block and I'm trying to pass in custom data (an icon to use within the div) when calling it, so something like (this is highly summarised!):

```
{{ form_row(signUpForm.email, {
    attr: { placeholder: 'e.g. bobsmith@gmail.com' },
    icon: 'envelope'
}) }}
```

then try to render in the form as

```
{%- block form_row -%}
<div>
    {{ form_label(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form, {attr: class: 'input'}) }}
    <i class="icon {{ icon }}"></i>
</div>
```

I tried also passing icon via the formBuilder, along the lines of

```
$builder
    ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
    'attr'=> ['icon' => 'envelope']
])
```

but no joy. Surely this must be possible! Any assistance would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: ... or even just to know if what I want to do isn't possible!

Comment: I think this link can help you https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#form-fragment-naming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to find the "proper" way to do what I want: a Form Type Extension. The [Symfony Casts tutorial](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-forms/form-type-extension) on it is pretty good. In short, you create a class to extend your main form input class; in my case I was dealing with a text based input, so I created an `App\Form\ypeExtension\TextIconExtension` class, extended from `FormTypeExtensionInterface`, then implemented `configureOptions` and `buildView` (I removed the functions in the interface I didn't fill in):

```
class TextIconExtension implements FormTypeExtensionInterface
{

public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $view->vars['icon'] = $options['icon'];
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'icon' => 'user'
    ]);
}

public function getExtendedType()
{
    return TextType::class;
}

public function getExtendedTypes(): iterable
{
    return [TextType::class];
}

}
```

Then, in my form template, I can simply pass a value for icon:

```
{{ form_row(signUpForm.email, {
    attr: { placeholder: 'e.g. bobsmith@gmail.com' },
    icon: 'envelope'
}) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can access to your form variable with {{form}} in your theme. So you can use it.
Hope this help

**Edit:**

You can add property in your entity and use it in template like this :

```
{%- block form_row -%}
<div>
    {{ form_label(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form, {attr: class: 'input'}) }}
    {% set myData = form.vars.value %}
    <i class="icon {% if myData.type == 'mail' %}envelope{% endif %}"></i>
```

I think you have a better way to do this but i do something like that and it's work.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of that and tried shoving data into the form object. However, any keys/field names you pass to the form object get validated by Symfony, so you can't add your own custom field names, very frustrating!